# Convert JSON nested data to dataframe in R

Tags: r, json

I have a json string that's is a nested dataframe and is full of characters that need to be escaped like `\n`, `\r` and `\`.  I have not been able to convert it with `jsonlite`.

[Here's a dput](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tMk4bGgS6pWfEGjBvmhRnUo5TiDTaFi5/view?usp=sharing) of the first element of the list.

`fromJSON(json_data)` gives the following error:

[image]

Replacing the character `"{"` with blank character is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the image of your data, there is `} {` which is not valid JSON. Regardless of providing any content *after* that point, until the content is real json, there's nothing you can easily do. One might think about using regular expressions to try to fix this, and ... if fixed-patterns (e.g., `json_data <- gsub("} {", "},{", json_data, fixed=TRUE)`), then it might work, but anything more is really ill-advised.

Comment: Thanks for the input @r2evans ; yeah, the string is full of rubble that needs to go to make it "real JSON"; but since I don't know what real JSON should look like (I understand that there distinct flavors?) I'm kind of lost on what to put in the `gsub`.

Comment: The only real differences I know of are: (1) json everything is a list-or-dict, e.g., `{"a":[1]}`; (2) json auto-unbox, e.g., `{"a":1}`; and the only odd one, newline-delimited json, in which each line is a complete json entity, this is useful for logs since you don't want to read in the entire file to be able to use one line. Other than that, there really are no flavors that I'm aware of. (No flavor of json allows no-comma between elements.)

Comment: Have you tried my `gsub` \*hack\*? It might be enough to get you past this stage.

Comment: I did and it worked; now I have to figure out how to reshape the resulting `fromJSON()` parsed data (it's in wide format that repeats columns for each value in that category). But it's a step ahead!

Answer (score 0):

This solution is meant to be a stop-gap for one known flaw in the json validation: two (or more) dictionaries are not separated by a comma. I discourage the use of regular expressions to fix this, but a fixed string-replacement can suffice:

```r
json_date <- gsub("} {", "},{", json_data, fixed = TRUE)
```